# Launch new modal from a previous modal

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Is it possible to launch a new modal when I click the submit button from a previous modal? I've been trying to do this all day and I'm stuck. I'm using CodeIgniter. I've tried to add another function in my `onclick` but it's not working.

Here's the button that triggers my modal:

```
<a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="modal" onclick="loadModuleForm('<?php echo $this->config->item('8L_URL')."/propertymgt/form/add"; ?>')"><span class="btn btn-primary">Create</span></a>
```

And this is my modal:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Property Management</h3>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="propertymgt-form" id="propertymgt-form" action="<?php echo $this->config->item('8L_URL')."/propertymgt/post/".$form_action; ?>" method="POST">
        <br />
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="title">Title:</label>
            <div class="controls" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title" name="title" class="span5" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">
            </div>
            <label class="control-label" for="fullname">Fullname:</label>
            <div class="controls" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" name="lastname" class="span3" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>">
                <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" name="firstname" class="span3" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>">
                <input type="text" id="middlename" placeholder="Middlename" name="middlename" class="span3" value="<?php echo $middlename; ?>">
            </div>
            <label class="control-label" for="address">Address:</label>
            <div class="controls" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                <input type="text" name="address" class="span3" id="address" placeholder="No., Street, Building" value="<?php echo $address; ?>">
                <input type="text" name="city" class="span3" id="city" placeholder="City" value="<?php echo $city; ?>">
                <input type="text"name="province" class="span3" id="province" placeholder="Province" value="<?php echo $province; ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden"name="uuid" class="span3" id="uuid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="registration-submit" onClick="submitForm('propertymgt-form');loadModuleForm('<?php echo $this->config->item('8L_URL')."/propertymgt/form/add"; ?>');">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</button>
</div>
```

The `loadmoduleform()` should load my new modal. Am I missing something? I need somebody's help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

u want something like this?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B9p6D/)

u just need to hide 1st modal n launch another modal on ur button click function

```
$('#newModal1').modal('hide');
$('#newModal2').modal('show');
```

Comment: Exactly! But it'll be complicated on my part. Thanks for the help. I might need this in the future. :)

Comment: yes..i can just show you simple demo..rather than using your code..you need to call function inside function so it will execute your  code..

Answer (score 0):

I just called the script for my function loadmoduleForm(). All I have to do now is to call for  a function where loadmoduleForm() is inside. Thanks anyway. :)